# Why wont the logo only show up only on the computer screen?

Tags: python, html, css, web

For some reason my logo will show up on the computer iphone and ipad screens but I want it to only show up on the computer screen. Can someone explain to me what the issue is ?

Here is my html and css code did I format it wrong somewhere ? Not sure if I am just missing a parentheses or my entire structure is incorrect.

```css
body {
  background-color: #000000;
}

.computer {
  #spin-gif {
    object-fit: cover;
    background-color: #000000;
    z-index: 1;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }

  #logo {
    object-fit: cover;
    background-color: transparent;
    z-index: 2;
    max-width: 50%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -10%;
  }
}

.iphone {
  #spin-gif-iphone {
    object-fit: cover;
    background-color: #000000;
    z-index: 1;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 10%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
}

.ipad {
  #spin-gif-ipad {
    object-fit: cover;
    background-color: #000000;
    z-index: 1;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 10%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
}

.iphone {
  display:none;
}

.ipad {
  display:none;
}

.computer {
  display:block;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:375px) {
  .computer {
    display:none;
  }

  .iphone {
    display:block;
  }

  .ipad {
    display:none;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:820px) {
  .computer {
    display:none;
  }

  .iphone {
    display:none;
  }

  .ipad {
    display:block;
  }

  #logo {
    display:none;
  }
}
```

```html
from flask import Flask,send_from_directory

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def home():
    page = """<html>

<head>
    <title> SPADE</title>
    <link href="static/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>

<div class="computer">
<img id="spin-gif" src="static/spin.gif" width="45%" height="75%">
<img id="logo" src="static/logosolo.svg" width="40%" height="76%">
</div>


<div class="iphone">
<img id="spin-gif-iphone" src="static/spin.gif" width="45%" height="75%">
</div>


<div class="ipad">
<img id="spin-gif-ipad" src="static/spin.gif" width="45%" height="75%">
</div>

</body>
</html>"""
    return page


app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=8081)
```